# How to make my image responsive width and height?

Tags: css

I wont my image to be responsive like the rest of my website will be. How do i make it adjust to the size of the container. Not just the width but also resize the height?

The image is in a container with a max-width of 1300px, so i have made a test image that has the sizes 400px height and 1300px width

Here is the jsfiddle so you can have a look at what i mean.
http://jsfiddle.net/z6fj8dtg/2/

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="codeback">
        </div>
        <div id="container">

        <div class="nav">
        </div>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div class="banner">
                <img src="http://s12.postimg.org/vnsghsvf1/banner.png" >
            </div><!-- END OF BANNER -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- END OF CONTAINER -->







 body{
        background-color:#272822;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }

        #wrapper{
            width:100%; 
            height:inherit;
        }
        #codeback{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            background-image:url('capture.jpg');
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
            position:fixed;
            left:0px;
            top:0px;
            z-index:-1;

        }
        #container{
            width:100%;
            float:right;

        }
        .nav{
            margin-top:200px;
            width:80%;
            max-width:1300px;
            height:50px;
            float:right;
            background-color:black;
            position:relative;

        }
.fixedNav {
    position:fixed;
    margin:0;
    width:80%;
    right:0;
}

        #wrap{
            float:right;
            width:80%;
            max-width:1300px;
            height:1500px;
            background-color:white;
            box-shadow: -1px -1px 35px lightblue;
        }
        .banner{        
            max-width:100%;
        }
```

At the minute it just sits in the container but overflows to the right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes that's no problem at all. Just insert the following CSS:

```
.banner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; //Auto adjust height (maintain aspect ratio)
}
```

Comment: I would probably also put in a max-width, so the image does not get larger than what it have to be.

Comment: Yeah that's no problem, but it's best if the container/wrapper does that job.

Comment: Thanks a lot , that has worked for me!, im new to responsive design and its taking a little time to get into.

I love stackoverflow, great community that actually help others unlike other websites!

Comment: Does it pass Lighthouse test?

Answer (score 0):

i used bootstrap image responsive class img-fluid and extra div tags to control image size.

```
      <div style="width: 20%;height: 100px">
        <img src="http://www.everlastingcelebrations.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Top-Ganesh-Chaturthi-Messages-Images-Photos.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
      </div>
```