# Images/content adjusting to page re-sizing, always maintaining structure

Tags: html, css

Here is what I am looking for: http://tinyurl.com/oe3ydvr. No matter the size of the window the html adjust's to fit and appear perfectly. I have examined the css code but I still can't figure it out. I read somewhere to do as follows:

```
  <style>
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  </style>
```

Everything I have attempted has fallen short. I would really appreciate some closure on this issue, Thanks jmr333:)

Comment: Might I suggest you investigate some of the following areas which are bound to help you understand this whole subject more clearly: "responsive design", "media queries". Actually those two should suffice to get you started.

Comment: ^ Better answer than the posted answer

Comment: Thank You, I do need to get a better understanding on the subject. I will be looking into "responsive design" && "media queries".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, there are a number of things going on here, the main slider container `slider1_container` is being ajusted to pixel-size that fits the viewport with javascript (with an img tag inside). The text blocks are not text, but images and scaled that way - a very bad practice from many standpoints. Your code relates to how a background image could scale "in a good way" while resizing the viewport

Comment: Thank you for the insight. . . When I re-size the example link the slide-show does what I want the entire site to do. Conform to the re-sizing of the switch.

Answer (score 1):

You can't style the background of your site like shown in your sample code, with properties directly on base level of your script tag. You always have to style a particular html element, i.e. `div`, or `body` or `html`, and assign properties in that context:

```
body {
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

See [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover) for examples on the background attribute.

In the mentioned site, there's actually complex javascript at work to style the top banner's (`#slider1_container`) width. This is easy to spot, because its inline css attributes get dynamically adjusted, while you change your browser window's width...

As a much simpler start, start with `max-width: 100%` as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25766844/444255).

I am guessing, most likely you'll want to start with a particular 100%-width-div (and certain elements on top), not the overall page background. (There is no need for javaScript on these basics )

Comment: However, there is no need for any javascript to control the size of the hero banner.

Comment: Thank you i will definitely be checking out what w3schools has on the issue at hand.